# R: How to upgrade a for-loop for this calculation?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have this matrix:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,4,3,5,7,5,7,6,6,9,
              5.9,9,11,8,4.5,5.5,7.9,
              21,6.7,13.6,3.5,5,6,6,
              7.9,1,67,4,2), ncol=3, byrow=T)
```

and this vector:

```
B <- c(2 ,3, 4)
```

With this code (only with `for-loop` ) (thank's to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4870695/jimbou in [How use (only) for-loop for this operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696126/how-use-only-for-loop-for-this-operation)):

```
res <- NULL
for (j in 1:3){
  for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
  if(i == 1) tmp2 <- NULL
  tmp <-   ifelse(( i-1+B[j] >nrow(A)),NA, sum(A[i:(i-1+B[j]),j])) 
  tmp2 <- rbind(tmp2,tmp);rownames(tmp2) <- NULL
  }
  res <- cbind(res,tmp2);colnames(res) <- NULL
}
```

I obtain this expected result:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]  4.0 14.0 22.9
 [2,]  8.0 21.0 26.9
 [3,] 11.0 27.0 27.8
 [4,] 15.0 25.5 35.4
 [5,] 13.5 23.2 35.5
 [6,] 25.5 17.2 28.5
 [7,] 24.5 19.6 22.6
 [8,]  9.5 16.9   NA
 [9,] 73.0   NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Now I would to multiply my matrix A in the loop, in  each operation, for respectively row, of this matrix `C`:

```
C
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]  1.0  4.0  5.0
 [2,]  2.0  7.0  6.0
 [3,]   NA  8.0  7.0
 [4,]   NA   NA  9.0
```

The new expected output (for example only for a first column) is:

```
    [1]
[1] 7.0  # = 1*1+ 3*2 =A[1,1]*C[1,1]+A[2,1]*C[2,1]
[2] 13.0 # = 3*1+5*2 = A[2,1]*C[1,1]+A[3,1]*C[2,1]
[3] 17.0 # = 5*1+6*2 = A[3,1]*C[1,1]+A[4,1]*C[2,1]
.....
[9]  140 # = 6*1+67*2 = A[9,1]*C[1,1]+A[10,1]*C[2,1]
```

and so on for all column of `A` respectivly for column of `C`.

I tried to insert `C[,j]` in the previous code, like here:

```
res <- NULL
    for (j in 1:3){
      for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
      if(i == 1) tmp2 <- NULL
      tmp <-   ifelse(( i-1+B[j] >nrow(A)),NA, sum(A[i:(i-1+B[j]),j]*C[,j])) 
      tmp2 <- rbind(tmp2,tmp);rownames(tmp2) <- NULL
      }
      res <- cbind(res,tmp2);colnames(res) <- NULL
    }
```

But it's not the correct code...Some idea?

Comment: I'm looking at this code right now, but as far as things that might help you out in the future.  Try to add some debugging code, e.g. just print out what is going on at each iteration of your loop, this can give you some insight into what is failing.

Comment: 1: In A[i:(i - 1 + B[j]), j] * C[, j] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
....

Comment: The output which code gives is only for the third column, i wrong somtehing in cbind or rbind i think...but i don't know

Comment: It looks like you just need to specify a range for the rows in C[,j]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one issue is subsetting `C`, note that in my answer below I changed `C` to `E`.

```
A <- matrix(
        c(1,   2,   4,   
          3,   5,   7,
          5,   7,   6,
          6,   9,   5.9,
          9,  11,   8,
          4.5, 5.5, 7.9,
         21,   6.7,13.6,
          3.5, 5,   6,
          6,   7.9, 1, 
         67,   4,   2), ncol=3, byrow=T)

B <- c(2 ,3, 4)

E <- matrix(c(
  1.0,  4.0,  5.0,
  2.0,  7.0,  6.0,
  NA ,  8.0,  7.0,
  NA ,   NA,  9.0), ncol=3,byrow=T)

# So what we are doing is taking row
# A[i:(i-1+B[j]) and summing it then multiplying it by
# the first column of C not including the NA's 
#
# It will create a matrix with the first three 
# rows like this
#  1+3, 2+5+7 , 4+7+6+5.9 
#  3+5, 5+7+9 , 7+6+5.9+8
#  5+6, 7+9+11, 6+5.9+8+7.9
# ...
#
# NAs are introduced at the bottom since the range
# of input exceeds the rows
#
#  The multiplication by C then has the typical dot
#  product form of 
#  1*1,  2*2+5*7+7*8 + ...
# ...

res <- NULL
for (j in 1:3){
 for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
   if(i == 1) tmp2 <- NULL
   tmp <-   ifelse(
     ( i-1+B[j] >nrow(A)),
     NA, 
     sum(A[i:(i-1+B[j]),j] * E[1:(1+j),j]) 
    )
    tmp2 <- rbind(tmp2,tmp)  
   }
 res <- cbind(res,tmp2)
 }

# easier to remove col and rownames at the end
colnames(res) <- NULL
rownames(res) <- NULL
```

The final output looks like this:

```
  [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]   7.0  99.0 157.1
[2,]  13.0 141.0 184.3
[3,]  17.0 179.0 192.5
[4,]  24.0 157.0 255.2
[5,]  18.0 136.1 236.6
[6,]  46.5 108.9 172.1
[7,]  28.0 125.0 129.0
[8,]  15.5 107.3    NA
[9,] 140.0    NA    NA
[10,]    NA    NA    NA
```